# Bind a domain name to a website in IIS Based on URL

Tags: iis, iis-8

Is it possible to bind a domain name to a website instance in IIS (Version 8.5) using a directory rather than a sub or second level domain?

For example:

1. domain.com/ = website1
2. domain.com/directory/ = website2

In the above example, instance 1 will obviously pick up both requests made in instance 1 and 2. I don't want to use a redirect.

Can anyone advise me on options?

Many thanks

Comment: Unless you can completely change IIS design and architecture, you won't get what you wanted by default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis However, by setting up a reverse proxy you can manipulate URLs as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is IIS reverse proxy. It use ARR and URL rewrite to do URL rewrite instead URL redirection.

You can easily rewrite ^/$ to website1 and ^/directory/$ to website2 with ARR.

Please install Application request routing and URL rewrite from Web platform installer. Then enable proxy in IIS manager->server node->application request routin cache->Server proxy setting->Enable Proxy.

Finally, you can input your rewrite rule in web.config.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing